# Radio Button value name

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i wanna ask how can i make a radio button from input and button

Html

```
 <input type="text" id="no" placeholder="No Soal">
    <select id="nilai">
      <option value="1">Benar</option>
      <option value="0">Salah</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="val" placeholder="Pilihan">
    <button onclick="myFunctions()">Judul</button>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function myFunctions() {
    var x = document.getElementById("no").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("nilai").value;
    var z = document.createElement("INPUT");
    z.setAttribute("type", "radio");
    z.setAttribute("name", x);
    z.setAttribute("value", y)
    document.body.appendChild(z);

}
</script>
```

I wanna get value from text id val and show it in `<input type="radio" name="1" value="0">HERE`

can anyone help?

Comment: Your code works what are you trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/fb8swaz1/

Comment: Please clarity, you want `<input type="radio" name="x" value="y">text from drop down` or  `<input type="radio" name="x" value="text from drop down">`?

Comment: like this <input type="radio" name="x" value="y">id="val"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve it by below code

```
var v = document.getElementById("val").value;
var text = document.createTextNode('id='+v);

document.body.insertBefore(text,z.nextSibling);
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/happenask/o3zLpwg6/)